# Propery Way to Redirect Automatic in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, apollo, apollo-client

I have an index page and I wanted to redirect to `/orders` page when he gets into the index page. What is the proper and correct way to do this? I'm using NextJS, Apollo Client and React.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import withApollo from '../apollo'

const Index = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  return router.replace('/orders')
}

export default withApollo(Index)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **For [redirect in Nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects), there is a setting in `next.config.js` you would need to add:**

You will need to add a `redirects` key to the settings:

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/orders',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What inside the Index page then?

Comment: This setting is running on the server-side, so your index page won't be rendered at all. You are free to remove it.

Comment: I'll delete index.page?

Comment: Yes! Because you always want to redirect to `/orders` when the user gets to `index` page, It's not necessary to keep the page anymore. Your index page will never be `render` again.